# Trouble using ProxyHandler with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, urllib2

I am trying to use proxy IP addresses in Selenium for web scraping. I am running Python 2.7.3 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 and I have the following python code

```
 import urllib2
 from selenium import webdriver

 fileproxylist = open('proxylist.txt', 'r')
 proxyList = fileproxylist.readlines()
 indexproxy = 0
 totalproxy = len(proxyList)


 def get_source_html_proxy(url, proxip):

     proxyip=urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':proxip})
     opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxyip)
     urllib2.install_opener(opener)
     req=urllib2.Request(url)
     sock=urllib2.urlopen(req)
     data = sock.read()
     return data

 browser = webdriver.Chrome()
 browser.get(get_source_html_proxy(MyUrl,proxyList[0]))
```

where `MyUrl` is the url of the address I want to scrap and `proxlist[0]` is the IP address I want to scrape from instead of the IP address of my local machine. When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Scrape.py", line 89, in <module>
         browser.get(get_source_html_proxy(MyUrl,proxyList[0]))
    File "Scrape.py", line 83, in get_source_html_proxy
         sock=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126,          
    in urlopen
         return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, 
    in open
         response = self._open(req, data)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, 
    in _open
         '_open', req)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, 
    in _call_chain
         result = func(*args)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, 
    in http_open
         return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, 
    in do_open
         raise URLError(err)

    urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is here. Can someone help me figure out what's going on? Thanks!